# Clearing last n lines in terminal

Tags: python, macos

I know you can use

```
sys.stdout.write("\033[F") 
sys.stdout.write("\033[K")
```

to delete the last line in the MacOS terminal with python3. However, I want to delete the last 40 lines in the terminal all at once. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the [list of Control Sequence Introducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) sequences.

You can use `\033[40A` to move up by 40 lines and `\033[J` to clear from the current cursor position to the end of the screen.

Comment: Is it possible to remove something that was printed out inside """ """. for example

`print("""

Hello there
This is a test
Message

""")`

Comment: `"""..."""` is just a multi-line string, it's otherwise the same as a regular `"..."` string with `\n` for newlines.